# Rails Many-to-many association with correct validation and save all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4.2.5 application I have the following two models (Spell, Category) which have a many-to-many relation with association model (Spellcategory):

```rb
class Spell < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :spellcategories, class_name: "Spellcategory", foreign_key: "spell_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :categories, through: :spellcategories, source: :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :spellcategories, class_name: "Spellcategory", foreign_key: "category_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :spells, through: :spellcategories, source: :spell
end

class Spellcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :spell, class_name: "Spell"
    belongs_to :category, class_name: "Category"
end
```

I have already an existing list of categories and want to import a list of spells. Because manual input is possible in the import process I want to first create everything, display it, and then save everything (spells + links to the categories) altogether.
I store the objects in the activerecord-session_store from the first to the second step.

I load the object with the following code from a XML file in the first step (a little bit pseudo-code because I don't want to bore you with all the XML parsing):

```rb
spells = xml_doc.path(...).map do |xml_spell|
    new_spell = @user.spells.build
    xml_spell.path('cats/cat').each do |node|
       new_spell.categories << Category.find_by(name: node.text) 
    end
    new_spell
end
```

and save all the spells in the second step.

```rb
if spells.map(&:valid?).all?
    spells.each(&:save!)
end
```

The last lines fail because validation fails with the error *Spellcategories is invalid*.
My guess is it has something to do with the unsaved child elements from the association table. I tried to use `:autosave` but it didn't solve the problem.

What am I doing wrong which prevents me from saving all in one go?

Comment: Why are you using the `:source` option in your `has_many  :through` association? It's not useful here, and the `:Category` with capital 'C' is wrong.

Comment: The capital 'C' was a type and I edited the post.

Comment: And thought I copied the  `:source` option from the `has_many :through` example in the rails documentation. But I just checked and its not there obviously. Removed it and had no impact on the result.

Comment: Yes the `:source` option did not harm, it was not incorrect, just redundant. From a quick look I think the problem is that you build the new spell, so it is not saved at that point. Rails will try to create the association but that won't succeed because new_spell does not have an id yet. Try with  `new_spell = @user.spells.create` (instead of build).

Comment: Thats exactly the point: I don't want to create it with `create` in the first step because this already stores the spell.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't create a many-to-many association if both the sides are not already stored. SpellCategory only contains spell_id and category_id, which won't exist before the spell and the category are saved.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need access to `Spellcategory` model per se, you can use `has_and_belongs_to_many` instead of two `has_many` and it will simplify things quite a bit.

If you do need it, the reason for the problem was outlined above in comments to the question -- you don't have an ID for `Spell` you are creating to be able to save relations with it. Here's what I would try -- two options:

**Option 1**. If you have just a few records:

```
Spell.transaction do
  spells = xml_doc.path(...).map do |xml_spell|
    new_spell = @user.spells.create
    xml_spell.path('cats/cat').each do |node|
       new_spell.categories << Category.find_by(name: node.text) 
    end
    new_spell
  end
end
```

Wrapping it into transaction guarantees the consistency. Replacing "build" with "create" initializes the Spell record before adding categories.

**Option 2**. If you have many records. I used this method for importing millions of records. Keep the join table class and then use bulk import plugin (like https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) to load data.

Comment: I understand the problem of not having the Id. But the objects still have the correct references. This is why it works with `has_and_belongs_to_many`. What I expected is the possibility to add some kind of additional meta information about the relation to make it work with `build`, and `has_many`.   But thx a lot it works with the removal of the explicit relation table.

Comment: You can keep the relation table. Just make sure you create the Spell objects before adding categories to them.